# PHP Convert string from dd/mm/yyyy to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS string for use with ms sql server?

Tags: php

I am hosting a php application on Windows server 2008 and using SQL Server 2008. I am having issues with inserting dd/mm/yyyy date strings in to the database.

How can I manually convert my dd/mm/yyyy string into the MS SQL Server date format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS within PHP code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = strtotime('11/01/2012');

$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions

```
$date=date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($date_in_ddmmyyyy));
```

Answer (score 0):

// e.g. '12/12/2040' will not work

```
$date = strtotime('12/12/2035');

if($date !== false)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s' , $date);
}
else
{
    $date = 'can\'t convert';
}
echo $date;
```